# Sorting algorithms - Bubble sort

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14

For pure practice purposes, I started implementing different sorting algorithms in modern C++ in a standard library style way (i.e. using templates on iterators). This is my version of bubble sort.

I do not really have any specific criteria I would like to have the code reviewed under, but instead appreciate any hints I can get, be they on performance, coding style, expressiveness etc.

The whole implementation lives inside the file **bubble_sort.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <utility>

template<typename Iterator, typename Comparator>
void bubble_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Comparator cmp) {
    bool swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (auto i = begin + 1; i != end; ++i) {
            auto& val0 = *i;
            auto& val1 = *(i - 1);
            if (cmp(val0, val1)) {
                std::swap(val1, val0);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}

template<typename Iterator>
void bubble_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    bubble_sort(begin, end, [] (const typename Iterator::value_type& v0,
                const typename Iterator::value_type& v1) { return v0 < v1; });
}
```

For reference, I also provide to you a file containing a `main`-method which sorts a small `std::vector` of random `unsigned`s in ascending as well as descending order:

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "bubble_sort.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned> vec;
    std::default_random_engine engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribution(0, 10000);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        unsigned num = distribution(engine);
        std::cout << num  << ' ';
        vec.push_back(num);
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    bubble_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    for (unsigned e : vec) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    bubble_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (unsigned v0, unsigned v1) {
            return v0 > v1;
        });

    for (unsigned e : vec) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend putting your functions into a namespace.

---

> ```
> for (auto i = begin + 1; i != end; ++i) {
> ```

By doing `begin + 1`, you require that `Iterator` is a [*RandomAccessIterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), whereas you only need an [*ForwardIterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator). Use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) instead:

```
for (auto i = std::next(begin); i != end; ++i) {
```

You could also use `std::next(begin, 1)` to be explicit.

Similarly, when you do `*(i - 1)`, you require that `Iterator` is a *RandomAccessIterator*. Replacing it with `std::prev` still requires that `Iterator` is a [*BidirectionalIterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). Unless you think that is a reasonable requirement (for some versions of bubblesort, it would allow it to be more efficient), don't do this.

Rewrite the for loop as so (or any variant where you keep track of the two):

```
for (auto i = begin, inext = std::next(begin); inext != end; ++i, ++inext) {
    auto& val0 = *inext;
    auto& val1 = *i;
    // ...
```

While we are discussing iterator categories, it's useful to name `Iterator` after the iterator category you require, so `FwdIter` or `ForwardIterator` would be better names.

---

> ```
> template<typename Iterator>
> void bubble_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
>     bubble_sort(begin, end, [] (const typename Iterator::value_type& v0,
>                 const typename Iterator::value_type& v1) { return v0 < v1; });
> }
> ```

Rather than manually writing out the comparator, use [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). I would use `std::less<>`, but you could use `std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>` if you wanted to.

```
template<typename Iterator>
void bubble_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    bubble_sort(begin, end, std::less<>{});
}
```

Actually, instead of doing this, you could put a default argument on the other overload of `bubble_sort`:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Comparator = std::less<>>
void bubble_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Comparator cmp = {})
```

There are two advantages I can think of by doing it this way:

1. Less code (only one function definition)
2. You avoid ADL problems

One problem with

```
template<typename Iterator>
void bubble_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    bubble_sort(begin, end, std::less<>{});
}
```

is that the `bubble_sort(begin, end, ...)` can activate ADL. If `Iterator` was, let's say, `mylibrary::vector<int>::iterator`, and if I wrote a `bubble_sort` in the namespace `mylibrary`, this `bubble_sort` call might call the one from the `mylibrary` namespace instead of the one we intended.

This is not good. As a rule of thumb, when writing generic code, avoid unqualified function calls like `bubble_sort(begin, end, ...)`; instead qualify it with the namespace: `::bubble_sort(begin, end, ...)`.

Comment: Your use of inext introduced a subtle bug. The sort will now show UB for empty or 1-element vectors.

Comment: @FRob I'm fairly sure I didn't introduce any bugs. The bug for an empty range was caught by another answer, and this version has no problem with ranges of size 1

Answer (score 11):

```
std::swap(val1, val0);
```

This hard codes `std::swap` as the function to use for swapping. C++ also has a powerful (and sometimes confusing) mechanism to allow multiple namespaces to be searched for a function: argument dependent lookup (ADL).

To make use of it call swap unqualified, which performs ADL to find `swap` functions in the namespaces of the arguments, but also add `std::swap` as a "fallback":

```
using std::swap;
swap(val1, val0);
```

For further information on why you want this see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28130671/1116364) as well as the top answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6380862/1116364) (but don't get confused about it's incorrect references to the points in the question).

Going further, the best approach is to use [`std::iter_swap(&val1, &val0)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) as deduplicator suggested. The standard describes its effects as "`swap(*a,*b)`" (where `a` and `b` are the parameters of `std::iter_swap`) and further imposes the "swappable" requirements, which state:

> An object t is swappable with an object u if and only if:
>
> - the expressions `swap(t, u)` and `swap(u, t)` are valid when evaluated in the context described below [..]
>
> The context in which `swap(t, u)` and `swap(u, t)` are evaluated shall ensure that a binary non-member function named “swap” is selected via overload resolution [..] on a candidate set that includes:
>
> - the two `swap` function templates defined in `<utility>` [..] and
> - the lookup set produced by argument-dependent lookup [..]
>
> ---
>
> [[N4296]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) §17.6.3.2/2,3

Comment: @DanielJour Thank you. I did not know about this "trick" (although, in hindsight, it seems kind of obvious).

Answer (score 11):

#### Speed

Of course we all know bubble sort is one of the slowest sorting algorithms<sup>1</sup>. It turns out, however, that stopping when an iteration is completed without a swap usually adds more overhead than it saves. I did a quick test with this code:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Comparator>
void bs2(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Comparator cmp) {
    for (auto j=end; j != begin; --j) {
        for (auto i = begin + 1; i != j; ++i) {
            auto& val0 = *i;
            auto& val1 = *(i - 1);
            if (cmp(val0, val1)) {
                std::swap(val1, val0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ran around 20-25% faster. Of course, if you actually care about speed, you'd probably want to switch to another algorithm entirely, but if you're going to do a bubble sort, you might as well at least use the variant that's consistently the fastest. There's another variant (often called the shakersort) which alternates between upward and downward iterations. This turns out to be still slower, as a rule.

#### Iterator dependent types

To find the value type associated with an iterator, you use:

```
const typename Iterator::value_type&
```

Instead of this, I'd use:

```
std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
```

For one example, this will allow the code to work with raw pointers as the "iterators", which the original code won't since pointers won't define a `value_type` member.

---

<sup>1. Short of those like bogosort that were invented specifically to be as slow as possible, of course.</sup>

Comment: I am under the impression that bubble sort is actually OK - or potentially preferable due to low overheads - for very small sets of data, or data which is almost in order.

Comment: @JWT, there are better variations of bubble sort, such as shaker sort and comb sort. There is a problem that bubble sort introduces, I believe it is called turtle and rabbit. Do note that comb sort requires `<=` to work.

Comment: @jwt: No. For nearly any situation where a bubble sort might work sort of OK, an insertion sort or selection sort will be better. Of those two, insertion sort is *usually* preferable, but if you have objects that are *much* cheaper to compare than to copy (e.g., an `int` key with a *lot* of attached data) a selection sort may be better.

Comment: I would be very interested in the actual data you gathered while testing. The main point I see for terminating early is, of course, for nearly ordered containers: Suppose you have a large number of items (let's say 10 million), but only one or two of those are out of order. Not terminating early will lead to nearly 10 million redundant iterations, which would likely be a huge speed killer. Of course, I understand that terminating early in the average case might not be beneficial due to optimizations etc.

Comment: The point about using `std::iterator_traits` is very good. I will probably switch to your version.

Answer (score 10):

I'll add this since nobody mentioned it: the code will cause undefined behavior on empty ranges.

Th reason is that `i != end` will not properly work since `i` is initialized with `i + 1`.

I recommend just doing the check at the beginning and returning if `std::distance(begin, end)` is less than two.

Comment: With the distance computed with `std::distance`, ideally.

Comment: @DanielJour, I meant that, but probably making more explicit is worth it. Thanks

Comment: @Incomputable Thanks, I totally didn't think about that edge case!

Comment: @BenSteffan, I recommend setting up a test. Just create new randomized vector in a loop, sort it, use `std::is_sorted`, from size 0 to 75'000. Every increment of the upper bound will increase runtime seriously. This should be pretty easy to setup.

Comment: @Incomputable In what context? I don't think your answer talks about speed (or time complexity), and neither do any of the comments.

Comment: @BenSteffan, I meant the generated vector size is gonna too big to complete in one second around that size. The test is gonna take too long if the  big number is used.

Comment: @Incomputable I understood that much, but I know about that (this is not an exercise in doing fast sorting; I am aware of the very bad performance of Bubble sort). Still, I don't see how your comments stand in any context to your answer. If you have any recommendations about speed, shouldn't you write that in your answer?

Comment: @BenSteffan, the test would catch the bug, and 75'000 should be thorough enough. It would be in context of correctness. Anyway, nvm. Nothing important.

Comment: @Incomputable I see. I think I do understand why the bug happens, so I don't think this will really be necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I can't see anything in the sort that other have not already commented on. But lets have a look at your main:

Prefer to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` rather than member functions. This will keep your code generic so that if you switch to using C arrays for `vec` the code will continue to work.

```
    bubble_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    // Like this:
    bubble_sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

When using range based loops prefer to use the `auto` type. This way if you change the underlying type of the container you don't need to change the `for` loop as this will adapt to the container content.

```
    for (unsigned e : vec) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }

    // Like this:
    for (auto const& e : vec) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
```

Another useful place to use `auto` is in lambda parameter values.

```
    bubble_sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [] (auto const& v0, auto const& v1) {
            return v0 > v1;
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your review. I just wrote the `main`-method as a quick test, not giving very much attention on good coding practices and the like. Still, I have to admit that I didn't even know there were non-member `std::begin` and `std::end`, so that at least will likely become useful (I do know about `auto`, but I tend to prefer to write out most of the typenames, because it makes the code easier to read in my opinion (still, your point about changing the underlying type is of course valid)).

Comment: @BenSteffan I agree you should always be explicit about typing (where it matters). The use of auto should be reserved for locations were the type does not matter explicitly but can be inferred. (range based for and lambda are the most obvious of those).